# One-to-many self-relation in prisma schema

Tags: database, prisma

I want to create a simple table:

```
Users
---
id
name
friends
```

`friends` field should be an array of other user ids. I'm trying to define a schema for this in `schema.prisma`:

```
model User {
  id      String  @id @default(uuid())
  name    String
  friends User[]
}
```

Saving the file autocompletes the schema to this:

```
model User {
  id      String  @id @default(uuid())
  name    String
  friends User[]  @relation("UserToUser")
  User    User?   @relation("UserToUser", fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId  String?
}
```

I'm not sure how to interpret this. I have read the [Prisma docs about one-to-many self relations](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations#one-to-many-self-relations), but since it states

> This relation expresses the following:
>
> - "a user has zero or one teachers"
> - "a user can have zero or more students"

I doubt it's what I want. How do I get the "a user can have zero or more students" without the "a user has zero or one teachers" part?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Here you need a relation where a `User` has one or more friends. This would result in a many-to-many self relation as a `User` can have many friends and also a `User` can be a friend of other `Users`.

This can be done as follows:

```
model User {
  id              String @id @default(uuid())
  name            String
  friends         User[] @relation("friends")
  friendsRelation User[] @relation("friends")
}
```

the `friendsRelation` is an extra field and can be ignored as it's only used to store the many-to-many relation.

Creating a `User` with friends would look something like this:

```
  await prisma.user.create({
    data: {
      name: 'user 1',
      friends: { create: [{ name: 'user 2' }, { name: 'user 3' }] },
    },
  })
```

And querying for all users and their friends would be:

```
await prisma.user.findMany({ include: { friends: true } })
```

Comment: Thank you! Understanding that I need many-to-many relationship instead of one-to-many made it "click"