# Prisma many to many self relation error due to @relation and generated type input

Tags: many-to-many, self-join, prisma, prisma2

Using Prisma `3.7.0`.

I'm following this example in the [docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations/self-relations#many-to-many-self-relations)

```
model Person {
  id         Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  name       String?
  followers  Follows[] @relation("follower")
  following  Follows[] @relation("following")
}

model Follows {
  follower    Person @relation("follower", fields: [followerId], references: [id])
  followerId  Int
  following   Person @relation("following", fields: [followingId], references: [id])
  followingId Int

  @@id([followerId, followingId])
}
```

Then I try creating a `User` along with the people they're `following`, with the below code.

```
const person = await prisma.person.create({
    data: {
      following: {
        create: [
          { following: { connect: { id: 1 } } }
        ]
      }
    }
  });
```

I'm getting the following (see what I did there :)) error.

```
/usr/src/app/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:34755
     const error2 = new PrismaClientValidationError(renderErrorStr(validationCallsite));
                    ^
 
 PrismaClientValidationError: Unknown arg `following` in data.following.create.0.following for type FollowsCreateWithoutFollowingInput. Did you mean `follower`?
 Argument follower for data.following.create.0.follower is missing.
 
     at Object.validate (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:34755:20)
     at PrismaClient._executeRequest (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:39749:17)
     at consumer (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:39690:23)
     at /usr/src/app/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:39694:49
     at AsyncResource.runInAsyncScope (node:async_hooks:199:9)
     at PrismaClient._request (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:39694:27)
     at request (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:39799:77)
     at _callback (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:40007:14)
     at PrismaPromise.then (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:40014:23) {
     clientVersion: '3.7.0'
 }
```

I believe the reason I'm getting this error is because the `following[]` relation creates an input as mentioned in the error message `FollowsCreateWithoutFollowingInput`, meaning it's expecting a `follower` relation and not a `following`, as the `following` will be the `Person` I'm currently creating, and I just need to tell it who is the `follower` `Person`.

However this doesn't make sense to me. When I'm creating a `Person` along with its people they're `following`, I understand that to be an array of `Persons` who the person I'm currently creating is `following`. If so, then a `Follows` record in the `following` array contains the current `Person` (the one I'm creating) as the `follower` relation and some other `Person` as the `following` relation. And the relation I should be inputting is the `following` and not the `follower`. Therefore the input type that prisma should generate should be `FollowsCreateWithoutFollowerInput` instead of `FollowsCreateWithoutFollowingInput`.

What am I missing, in my understanding?

I looked at the below resources during my research on this.

1. [count self relation on Prisma error: table name specified more than once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68432776/count-self-relation-on-prisma-error-table-name-specified-more-than-once). This is discussing a different issue, using the same example.
2. https://github.com/prisma/prisma/discussions/3960. This discusses how to create the same type of relation, where the join table references the same table for both ids. But it doesn't explain how to create records once the relationships are defined.
3. [One-to-many self-relation in prisma schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65162657/one-to-many-self-relation-in-prisma-schema).  This shows how to create a record, but its not using the join tables relation during create it's using a property. Also it's not exactly the same case as the join table seems to be the same table.

Comment: I also found the explicit many-to-many self-relations challenging - was never able to get it working. You should be able to achieve something similar implicitly - https://gist.github.com/OffBy0x01/50ca1386cbddc7b3aad170def8da3c6c Perhaps you could compare the migration of an implicit relation to the migration of an explicit relation to see how they differ?

Answer (score 0):

```
`const person = await prisma.person.create({
    data: {
      following: {
        connect: { id: 1 }
      }
    }
  });
```

It's the "create" in the body of the function that's doing it. The second nested following would also cause a problem if you just fix that though.

Think of it like you aren't creating the follower. The follower already needs to be there. You are just creating a record of the connection between the person and the follower. So prisma.person.create some data that this person has a follower and that follower is connected to the user with id whatever.